# **Compiler error** - getline() function not accepting first parameter "std:ifstream" what is my issue?

Tags: c++

I'm writing a program for my homework that counts words and lines. I'm wondering why i get the error: "no instance of overloaded function "getline" matches the argument list. Argument types are (std::ifstream, int)" 
I was certain "infile" was of std::ifstream argument type. Could the problem be visual studio or am i quick to blame something without prior knowledge?
P.S i searched a bit but would not find a thread with exactly the same problem.. there are similar ones but they end up being that someone put a string of the file name and not the stream itself. ***Also keep in mind i'm in the middle of writing this i didn't finish yet.***

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;



int main()
{

ifstream infile;
infile.open("Lear.txt");
string word;
int countWords = 0, countLines = 0;
while (!infile.eof())
{
    infile >> word;
    countWords++;
    getline(infile, countLines); //issue area here at infile
    countLines++;

}
cout << "Words: " << setw(9) << countWords << endl;
cout << "Lines: " << setw(9) << countLines << endl;
infile.close();

}
```

Comment: @NathanOliver This question is about a compiler error...

Comment: `while (!infile.eof())` is almost never correct, you should be doing `while (infile >> word)` instead. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/5605125/981959

Answer (score 1):

There is no [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) overload that takes an `int` second parameter. I assume you meant to pass your `std::string` variable instead.

```
getline(infile, word);
```

You should remove the `infile >> word;` line or decide whether you want to use it or `std::getline`. I don't think you want both in this case.

This will fix the compiler error but not your program logic. If you use `std::getline` you'll have to parse each line to count words.

Comment: Then i believe this has been solved. It seems to have been an error on my part after all. Thanks for the advice and sorry to have wasted any time.